# MSSQL Trigger Update using Inserted Table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger that will only run if the updated column is equal to a specific value.

Basicly, Only when I update column name "Status" to value "Paid" do I want the trigger to run.

ie

```
if (Update(Status) AND  inserted.Status = 'Paid')
begin
end
```

At the moment I get this error 
"The multi-part identifier "inserted.Status" could not be bound."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your trigger code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split it into two steps. 1. only react if status is updated, 2. do what you want on all elements in inserted that has the status Paid

```
if update(status)
begin
    -- Do the stuff to the Paid elements in inserted
    select * from inserted as i where i.status = 'Paid'

end
```

remember that you status can also be updated from Paid to Paid, and you may not want to react on that. So you can do something like:

```
select * from
inserted as i
inner join deleted as d on i.id = d.id
where i.status <> d.status and i.status = 'Paid'
```

Now the result only contains the rows that has been updated to Paid and where it not already was equal to Paid